# ClassCastException caused by wrapping data type in Optional

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

Problem: I get the following error log -> `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDateTime`

Problem possible caused by : The return type is Optional which means jpa having difficulties mapping it since it recognizes optional and not the actual LocalDateTime data type.

Did anyone have any thoughts on how to  fix this? i mean i could return an object and its working just fine but i simply need a single value to be returned

works:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from audit where type='REQUEST_DOC_ONLINE' and user_id=:userId order by timestamp desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<AuditEntity> getLatestRetrievalDocumentDateAndTime(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

does not work:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from audit where type='REQUEST_DOC_ONLINE' and user_id=:userId order by timestamp desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<LocalDateTime> getLatestRetrievalDocumentDateAndTime(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

Comment: Could you show us AuditEntity class?

Comment: If you want to see what is the data type of the time stamp is the data type i am trying to return LocalDateTime @Ismail

Comment: try to replace LocalDateTime with Date, and then convert it yourself to LocalDateTime, a timestamp can not be converted to LocalDateTime.

Comment: @Ismail if it cant then taking the whole object its okey. Where did that info came from by the way?

Comment: Try to select timestamp column only. Replace `SELECT * from audit where...` with `SELECT timestamp from audit where...`

Answer (score 0):

1. You are fetching all columns and trying to cast it to `LocalDateTime`. I would rather suggest you select only the columns which have `LocalDateTime` as a datatype.
2. I also think you are probably using `Timestamp` or `Instant` as datatype in the `AuditEntity` class. If so, try using the same class while fetching.

Comment: I have explained above what work and what does not , that is regarding your first point.  And about the second point you made -> i do not use such type and i use LocalDateTime , thanks for the effort anyway

Comment: In that case, try creating POJO for mapping the columns which you require and then use that in the fetch statement.

Comment: As shown above i only need a single value which is timestamp

Comment: change `select *` to `select timestamp`